# How to extract coffee grounds from used Nespresso capsules?

Tags: kitchen, drinks, gardening

I drink about 100 cups of coffee per month... and now I'd like to find a practical way of getting the coffee grounds out of the used Nespresso capsules - so that I can use it as a fertilizer!

[image: Used coffee capsule]

Comment: Apart from the obvious method of using a knife to cut away the seal, you mean?

Answer (score 3):

You can just chop it open with a big knife, as can be seen in this YouTube video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oXhvZC4wNA0

Comment: Yes, but you don't need to waste a fresh page (or more) of a notebook as in the video: a newspaper will do :)

Comment: @WeatherVane lol of course, can also do it right above the plant/ground to be fertilized. :)